# I have downloaded a laravel project from github then run it and facing this error-

Tags: laravel

(1/1) ErrorException
file_put_contents(C:\Users\User\Downloads\LaraBook-Social-Network-in-laravel-5.4-master\LaraBook\storage\framework/sessions/wqLdjbArJFI09ZvoAn547vHfNrNRNN1w4Qg5C4jq): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Please share any relevant code.

Comment: use this command `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have the storage folder in that laravel project. So manually create te folder or copy from another project and paste in this project